# AutoCompletetextView issue with Nexus (Maybe is 4.0.X)

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, autocompletetextview

My issue is that I have a big, enormous list for the AutoComplete.
Example:

1. Store A
2. Store B
3. Store C
4. Store D
5. Store F
6. Store H
7. Store I

As you can see they all use Store and when I start typing store I see the (...) in the phone, where I can see the other stores, but if I chose one inside that (...) it will be added to the AutoComplete and not handle by the OnItemClick. Is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks in advice

Example Pics
[image]
Here is the Store Search

[image]
Here I clicked Store B and you can see the Toast that it was handle by OnItemClick

[image]
Here you can see the (...) extra stores.[image]
and finally you can see that it was added to the AutoCompleteTextView instead of handled by the OnItemClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was ICS issue, now that I'm at JB the issue is gone.